# How to implement final conditions properly?

Tags: c++

This is what I'm trying to do (this is a simplification of a real project):

```
int param;
int result;
void isolated(int p) {
  param = p;
  try {
    // make calculations with "param" and place the
    // result into "result"
    process();
  } catch (...) {
    throw "problems..";
  }
}
```

I can't change the way `process()` works, since this function is not created in the project and is a third-party function. It works with global variables `param` and `result` and we can't change this.

The problem appears when `isolated()` is called back from `process()` with another parameter. I want to catch this situation, but don't know how to do it, since `finally` is absent in C++. I feel that I should use [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) technique, but can't figure out how to do it in this case properly.

This is how I can make it with code duplication:

```
int param;
int result;
void isolated(int p) {
  static bool running;
  if (running) {
    throw "you can't call isolated() from itself!";
  }
  running = true;
  param = p;
  try {
    // make calculations with "param" and place the
    // result into "result"
    process();
    running = false;
  } catch (...) {
    running = false; // duplication!
    throw "problems..";
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. What do you want to do? (Assume `finally` exists)

Comment: The problem is that I should drop *the flag* in `catch` and in `try`, which is obviously code duplication. I will extend the question now

Comment: It's is not quiet clear what is throwing an exception at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't quite sure how `finally` is related here, but you could try [Boost.ScopeExit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/scope_exit/doc/html/index.html) if you want to avoid creating a scope guard structure yourself.

Example:

```
#include <boost/scope_exit.hpp>
#include <cstdio>

int isolated(int p) {
    static bool running = false;
    if (running) {
        printf("Throwing %d\n", p);
        throw p;
    }
    printf("Starting %d\n", p);
    running = true;
    BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT( (p)(&running) ) {   // <--
        printf("Stopping %d\n", p);       // <--
        running = false;                  // <--
    } BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT_END                // <--

    // ...
    if (p)
        isolated(p*10);
    // ...
    printf("Returing %d\n", p);

    return 4;
}

int main() {
    printf(">> first\n");
    isolated(0);
    printf(">> second\n");
    try {
        isolated(1);
        printf(">> third (should not be printed.)\n");  
    } catch(int p) {
        printf("Caught %d\n", p);
    }
    isolated(0);
    printf(">> fourth\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
>> first
Starting 0
Returing 0
Stopping 0
>> second
Starting 1
Throwing 10
Stopping 1
Caught 10
Starting 0
Returing 0
Stopping 0
>> fourth
```

Answer (score 5):

"finally" like situations are handled in C++ using guard objects, that do their finally thing in the destructor. This is IMHO much more powerful approach, because you have to analyze the situation to finalize in order to create a reuseable object. In this case, we need to make process rentrant, because parameters and returns are passed in globals. The solution is to save their values on entry and restore them on exit:

```
template<class T>
class restorer 
{
 T &var; // this is the variable we want to save/restore
 T old_value; // the old value
 restorer(const restorer&); 
 void operator=(const restorer&); 
 public:
 restorer(T &v) : var(v), old_value(v) {}
 ~restorer() { var=old_value; }
};

int param;
int result;
int isolated(int p) {
  restorer<int> rest_param(param);
  restorer<int> rest_result(result);

  param = p;
  try {
    // make calculations with "param" and place the
    // result into "result"
    process();
    return result;
  } catch (...) {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for good RAII. Except that it doesn't make isolated reentrant unless you use a lock on the global variables (with which you deal using RAII).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I didn't get it right, but why don't you use a flag? You want to know when the isolated() is called from the process(), right?

```
int isolated(int p) {
    static int execDeep = 0;
    execDeep++;

    // your code here

    execDeep--; 
}
```

Now you can check 'execDeep' value, > 1 means it is called from the process() while still being executed.

Answer (score 0):

Could this work?

```
int save = -10000000000;
int param;
int result;

int isolated(int p) {

  if (save != -10000000000)
  {  
    // run the other condition
  }
  else
  {  
     save  = p;
     param = p;
     try {
        // make calculations with "param" and place the
        // result into "result"
        process();
        return result;
     } catch (...) {
       return 0;
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to automatically set the running flag to false at the end of function. If that is the requirement then you can use the [ScopeGuard](http://www.drdobbs.com/184403758) approarch mentioned in the link.